# cordova-plugin-inappbrowser on Windows 10 mobile

Tags: ionic2, windows-10-mobile, auth0

I'm building an Ionic2 app using Auth0 Lock for authentication. Auth0 requires in-app-browser plugin for Cordova, and it seems to be doing alright on the Android device, but I can't get it to work on Windows 10 Mobile device.

The in-app-browser seems to be compatible with Windows Phone 8/8.1, but there is no mention of 10:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/